# Через геокодирование выводит круги на карту, а по координатами из массива нет https://darabotaet.ru/map1.html

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, yandex-geocoding-api

Вывожу круги с координатами городов по названиям через геокодирование. Все работает. Вывожу круги с координатами из массива json. Выводит в Африке странную сетку.

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxx" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function declOfNum(n, text_forms) {  
    n = Math.abs(n) % 100; 
    var n1 = n % 10;
    if (n > 10 && n < 20) { return text_forms[2]; }
    if (n1 > 1 && n1 < 5) { return text_forms[1]; }
    if (n1 == 1) { return text_forms[0]; }
    return text_forms[2];
}
var data = [
        {
            "city": "Москва",
            "choord": "55.755864, 37.617698",
            "qty": "1632"
        },
        {
            "city": "Екатеринбург",
            "choord": "56.838011, 60.597474",
            "qty": "160"
        },
        {
            "city": "Санкт-Петербург",
            "choord": "59.938955, 30.315644",
            "qty": "1155"
        }, {
            "city": "Белово",
            "choord": "54.42212,86.303701",
            "qty": "2"
        }
    ];var myMap;
ymaps.ready(init);        
function init() {
    myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: [55.76, 37.64],
        zoom: 5
    }, {
        searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
    });
var table = document.createElement('table'), tr, td, row, cell;
    data.forEach(function(row) {
        
        
        
        
        
        ymaps.geocode(row.city).then(function (res) {
            var coord = res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates();
            
            
             tr = document.createElement('tr');
    
        td = document.createElement('td');
        tr.appendChild(td);
        td.innerHTML = row.city;
            td2 = document.createElement('td');
        tr.appendChild(td2);
        td2.innerHTML =  coord;
            td3 = document.createElement('td');
        tr.appendChild(td3);
        td3.innerHTML =  row.qty;
     
    table.appendChild(tr);
            
            
            
         
            
                var myCircle = new ymaps.Circle([
        // Координаты центра круга.
        row.choord,
        // Радиус круга в метрах.
        200*row.qty
    ], {
         
        // Содержимое хинта.
        hintContent: coord + " " + row.city + " " + row.choord
    }, {
         
        // Последний байт (77) определяет прозрачность.
        // Прозрачность заливки также можно задать используя опцию "fillOpacity".
        fillColor: "#99006677",
        // Цвет обводки.
        strokeColor: "#990066",
        // Прозрачность обводки.
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        // Ширина обводки в пикселях.
        strokeWidth: 5
    });

    // Добавляем круг на карту.
    myMap.geoObjects.add(myCircle);
            
                
            setCenter();
        }, function (err) {
            setCenter();
        });     
    });
    
    document.getElementById('tabl').appendChild(table);
}
 
var placemark_index = 0;
function setCenter(){
    placemark_index += 1;
    if (data.length == placemark_index) {
        myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds(),{checkZoomRange:true, zoomMargin:9});
    }
}
 
</script>
    <div id="tabl"></div>
```

Json взят из таблички с координатами, которые выдаёт api Карт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Координаты в API Яндекс Карт это не строки, а массивы должны быть.
Замените кавычки на скобки []:

```
{
 "city": "Москва",
 "choord": [55.755864, 37.617698],
 "qty": "1632"
}
```

и карта заработает как надо: https://jsbin.com/xosenew/edit?js,output

Comment: Спасибо большое!!